# My program becomes unresponsive while performing a loop (Lazarus)

Tags: loops, pascal, repeat, lazarus, unresponsive-progressbar

I wrote  a simple graphical program. It seemed to work, but when I clicked the Button (Button1), the program became unresponsive and began to respond only when the assigned procedure ended. I was using the simple Repeat...Until loop.
Here's the procedure:

```
procedure TSlashForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Repeat
  //some code
 until //some condition;
end;
```

If I click the form during the execution of the loop, the whole program becomes unresponsive and crashes. To fix this, I have tried to use

```
SlashForm.Update;
```

and

```
SlashForm.Refresh;
```

but none of these seemed to work. How can I avoid the unresponsive state?

Comment: _If you create an application, and when the user presses a button the application starts processing a big job... and while processing, the screen stops responding, and gives the user the impression that the application is frozen, a poor or misleading impression will be created._ - citation from [Multithreaded Application Tutorial](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Multithreaded_Application_Tutorial) article. Read it for more info about your problem and possible solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or call application.processmessages in the loop every 100-1000 iterations or so. (or roughly 5-10 times a second if you have slow iterations)

Comment: Be careful with ProcessMessages, it's the quick bodge fix when people don't want to go through the effort of threads, but comes with its own problems: http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/delphi-processmessages-dark-side.htm

Comment: Processmessages should never be used without understanding it, but in itself it is not really a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use multithreading. In this variant, your program responds to clicking the button by creating a thread that performs your loop:

```
type
  TAThread = class(TThread)
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure SafeFree;
  end;

theThread: TAThread;

procedure TAThread.Execute;
var
  //some variables
begin
  repeat
  // some code
  until // some condition
end;

procedure TSimulationThread.SafeFree;  {avoids a dead-lock situation}
begin
  Terminate;
  WaitFor;
  if not FreeOnTerminate then
    Free;
end;

procedure TSlashForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if assigned(theThread) then
    theThread.Execute
  else
    theThread := TAThread.Create(false);
end;
```

See http://sourceforge.net/p/simthyr/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/simulator.pas for a working example.